# how to add stm32l4s5 to IAR Embedded Work Bench?

Tags: embedded, stm32, iar, stm32ldiscovery

Am working in a project in which I use Stm32cubemx to generate C Code For drivers like UART and SDMCC using STM32L4S5xx and when I generated my code for IAR , Unknown target error is found...

The error clearly that IAR is not supporting my target.
[image: The error clearly that IAR is not supporting my target.]

now when searching for my target I did not find it in the IAR supported target so how to add my target?

No STM32l4xxx options:
[image: No STM32l4xxx options]

Comment: Maybe upgrade to a newer version of IAR EWARM.  Or ask IAR.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IAR EWARM release notes](https://netstorage.iar.com/SuppDB/Public/UPDINFO/013322/arm/doc/infocenter/device_support/STMicroelectronics.ENU.html#STM32L4Sxx) your STM32L4S5 MCU is supported since EWARM v8.20.1. Looking at your screenshot it looks like you are using a version prior to v8.xx.
You need to upgrade to EWARM v8.20.1 or newer for your project.